# adding parent to xml doc in perl

Tags: perl, parent, addition, libxml2

I have a problem of adding parent to the xml document. I got xml:

```
<book id="bk104">
  <author>Corets, Eva</author>
  <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
  <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
  agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
  for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
  Ascendant.</description>
</book>
```

and I want to add parent tag to the book so it would be:

```
<library>
 <book id="bk104">
  <author>Corets, Eva</author>
  <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
  <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
  agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
  for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
  Ascendant.</description>
 </book>
</library>
```

I'm using `XML::LIBXML`, I've tried to get root

```
my $root = $doc->getDocumentElement;
```

and create new element

```
my $new_element= $doc->createElement("library");
```

and then

```
$root->insertBefore($new_element,undef);
```

Finally :

```
my $root = $doc->getDocumentElement;
my $new_element= $doc->createElement("library");
$parent = $root->parentNode;
$root->insertBefore($new_element,$parent);
```

but it wont work. Also tried to find parent of root which returns header node, and then `addchild` but it does not work either.

Comment: Better show your real full script

Comment: my $root = $doc->getDocumentElement;
 my $new_element= $doc->createElement("library");

 $parent = $root->parentNode;
 $root->insertBefore($new_element,$parent);

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece:

```
open my $in, '<:encoding(utf-8)', 'in.xml';
my $document = XML::LibXML->load_xml(IO => $in);

my $root     = $document->documentElement();
my $new_root = $document->createElement('library');
$new_root->appendChild($root);
$document->setDocumentElement($new_root);

open my $out, '>:encoding(utf-8)', 'out.xml';
print $out $document->toString();
```

It creates *new_root* element, appends *root* element to *new_root* as a child and set *new_root* element as root element for document.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new, empty `library` element and set it as the new root element of the document. Then add the old root as a new child.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => << '__END_XML__');
<book id="bk104">
  <author>Corets, Eva</author>
  <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
  <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
  agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
  for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
  Ascendant.</description>
</book>
__END_XML__

my $book = $doc->documentElement;
my $library = $doc->createElement('library');
$doc->setDocumentElement($library);
$library->appendChild($book);

print $doc->toString(1);
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<library>
  <book id="bk104">
    <author>Corets, Eva</author>
    <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
    <genre>Fantasy</genre>
    <price>5.95</price>
    <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
    <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
  agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
  for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
  Ascendant.</description>
  </book>
</library>
```

Comment: yes, thats workin for me but I did not realise it does not solve my problem cause im processing xml query, so Im parsing after adding new root, but i need to add it there after parsing my final data. Lets say I need to parse <author> from <book> but <author> nodes have to have <library> as root written in output. Im parsing with find : my $_demo = $root->find("//$sel_element"); where $sel_element is "book" node for this example. And I cant apend new root like $new_root->appendChild($_demo); cause I get appendchild error. How should I do it to add it after I have my final parsed data?

Comment: @user2158951: Your problem isn't at all clear. You will have to show a full example of what you want to do, including the input and the order it arrives, and the desired output XML structure. Please edit your question for this.

Comment: The reason your example doesn't work is that `$root->find("//book")` returns a `XML::LibXML::NodeList` object, and `$new_root->appendChild` expects an `XML::LibXML::Node`. You have to say whether you want append the first node in the list, or loop through all of them appending each one.